# Pop-up on word hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, display

I want to display a pop-up with text whenever I hover on orange text but I'm struggling with two different situations with the code I wrote:

1) The pop-up's are already showing when you land on the page. If I try `display: none` on the "popup" class, they will never show.

2) I want them to be relative to the word, not to the whole paragraph, but I dont know how to stablish `position: relative` on the "choose" class as It's a span tag and It doesn't seem to allow that.

```js
function showPopupAmplitud() {
  const popup = document.getElementById('popup_amplitud');
  popup.style.display = "";
}

function hidePopupAmplitud() {
  const popup = document.getElementById('popup_amplitud');
  popup.style.display = "none";
}

function showPopupDAW() {
  const popup = document.getElementById('popup_daw');
  popup.style.display = "";
}

function hidePopupDAW() {
  const popup = document.getElementById('popup_daw');
  popup.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 42%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.popup_container {
  position: relative;
}

.choose {
  color: #FFAC3E;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup {
  padding: 0px 15px 25px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #6A6A6A;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22.7px;
}

.popup p {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <article>
    <div class="popup_container">
      Nuestro objetivo es que la <span class="choose" onmouseover="showPopupAmplitud()" onmouseout="hidePopupAmplitud()">amplitud</span> de la señal proporcionada por el sintetizador disminuya algunos decibeles cada vez que suene el redoblante. Lo que
      hacemos es asignar un compresor al canal del sintetizador, y mediante el routeo entre ambos canales, activar la opción de Sidechain que tal compresor nos proporciona (no todos los compresores poseen la alternativa de ser utilizados como Sidechain).</br>
      </br>
      <div class="popup" id="popup_amplitud">
        <p>La amplitud de un movimiento oscilatorio, ondulatorio o señal electromagnética es una medida de la variación máxima del desplazamiento u otra magnitud física que varía periódica o cuasiperiódicamente en el tiempo. Es la distancia entre el punto
          más alejado de una onda y el punto de equilibrio o medio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_container">
      En la seccion Mixer del <span class="choose" onmouseover="showPopupDAW()" onmouseout="hidePopupDAW()">DAW</span> a utilizar, se deberá routear el canal que posee asignado el Trigger al canal de la señal a afectar (en el caso de ser FL Studio como
      se muestra en la imagen, se hace click derecho en la flecha inferior y a continuacion “Sidechain to this track”, lo cual generará un enlace entre ambos canales).</br>
      </br>
      <div class="popup" id="popup_daw">
        <p>Una estación de trabajo de audio digital (EAD) o DAW por sus siglas en inglés (Digital Audio Workstation) es un sistema electrónico dedicado a la grabación y edición de audio digital por medio de un software de edición de audio.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of setting `style.display`, toggle the existence of a class that has the `display: none` you want, and have the class on your elements by default. You can use `classList.toggle('classNameYouChose')`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for JavaScript here as the `:hover` pseudo selector will work perfectly in CSS. When hovering your `.choose` element select the `.popup` element with the sibling selector (`~`) and set the desired state.

Like this:

```
.choose:hover ~ .popup { 
  ...
}
```

However, I'd suggest changing up your HTML structure. Turn `.popup` element into a `<span>` and place it inside the `.choose` span element. This way you can position your popup relatively to the position of the `.choose` element. And you don't have to use the sibling selector now that `.popup` is a child of `.choose`.

Position your popup with both the `left` and `transform` properties to place them right below the word that has been hovered.

See the example below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 42%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.popup_container {
  position: relative;
}

.choose {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFAC3E;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 25px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #6A6A6A;
  position: absolute;
  width: fit-content;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 22.7px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.choose:hover .popup,
.popup:hover {
  display: block;
}

.popup p {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <article>
    <div class="popup_container">
      <p>
      Nuestro objetivo es que la <span class="choose">amplitud
          <span class="popup" id="popup_amplitud">
            La amplitud de un movimiento oscilatorio, ondulatorio o señal electromagnética es una medida de la variación máxima del desplazamiento u otra magnitud física que varía periódica o cuasiperiódicamente en el tiempo. Es la distancia entre el punto
          más alejado de una onda y el punto de equilibrio o medio.
          </span>
        </span> de la señal proporcionada por el sintetizador disminuya algunos decibeles cada vez que suene el redoblante. Lo que hacemos es asignar un compresor al canal del sintetizador, y mediante
      el routeo entre ambos canales, activar la opción de Sidechain que tal compresor nos proporciona (no todos los compresores poseen la alternativa de ser utilizados como Sidechain).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_container">
      <p>
      En la seccion Mixer del <span class="choose">DAW<span class="popup" id="popup_daw">
        Una estación de trabajo de audio digital (EAD) o DAW por sus siglas en inglés (Digital Audio Workstation) es un sistema electrónico dedicado a la grabación y edición de audio digital por medio de un software de edición de audio.
      </span></span> a utilizar, se deberá routear el canal que posee asignado el Trigger al canal de la señal a afectar (en el caso de ser FL Studio como se muestra en la imagen, se hace click derecho en la flecha
      inferior y a continuacion “Sidechain to this track”, lo cual generará un enlace entre ambos canales).
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this worked pretty well!

But now I added some paragraphs between the two hovereable words so now they are scroll separated. Whenever I try to hover on "DAW", the page inmediately scrolls towards the start of <article>

Answer (score 0):

For question 1 Use this:

```
    .popup_container{display:none;}

    .choose:hover + .popup_container {position:relative;display:auto;}
```

For question 2:

You need to declare the position of the .choose item, put the .popup_container within the .choose div, and then position it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So what i changed the code a bit and i attached the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` listeners to `draw` and `amplitud`.  Initiallly i set the popup `dispay` to `none` and on mouseover set it empty string. Also i applied `z-index` to the `popup` class so that the popup is above the text everytime

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // DOM Elements
  const draw = document.getElementById("draw");
  const popupdraw = document.getElementById("popup_daw");
  const amplitud = document.getElementById("amplitud");
  const popupamplitud = document.getElementById("popup_amplitud");

// Event Listeners
  amplitud.onmouseover = function() {
    popupamplitud.style.display = "";
  };
  amplitud.onmouseout = function() {
    popupamplitud.style.display = "none";
  };

  draw.onmouseover = function() {
    popupdraw.style.display = "";
  };
  draw.onmouseout = function() {
    popupdraw.style.display = "none";
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 42%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.popup_container {
  position: relative;
}

.choose {
  color: #ffac3e;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup {
 padding-top:15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #6a6a6a;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  top: 30px;
  left:50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22.7px;
  z-index: 400;
    display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.popup p {
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="text">
      <article>
        <div class="popup_container">
          Nuestro objetivo es que la <span class="choose" id="amplitud">amplitud</span> de la señal proporcionada por el sintetizador disminuya algunos decibeles cada vez que suene el redoblante. Lo que
          hacemos es asignar un compresor al canal del sintetizador, y mediante el routeo entre ambos canales, activar la opción de Sidechain que tal compresor nos proporciona (no todos los compresores poseen la alternativa de ser utilizados como Sidechain).</br>
          </br>
          <div class="popup" id="popup_amplitud" style="display:none">
            <p>La amplitud de un movimiento oscilatorio, ondulatorio o señal electromagnética es una medida de la variación máxima del desplazamiento u otra magnitud física que varía periódica o cuasiperiódicamente en el tiempo. Es la distancia entre el punto
              más alejado de una onda y el punto de equilibrio o medio.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_container">
          En la seccion Mixer del <span class="choose" id="draw">DAW</span> a utilizar, se deberá routear el canal que posee asignado el Trigger al canal de la señal a afectar (en el caso de ser FL Studio como
          se muestra en la imagen, se hace click derecho en la flecha inferior y a continuacion “Sidechain to this track”, lo cual generará un enlace entre ambos canales).</br>
          <br/>
          <div class="popup" id="popup_daw" style="display:none">
            <p>Una estación de trabajo de audio digital (EAD) o DAW por sus siglas en inglés (Digital Audio Workstation) es un sistema electrónico dedicado a la grabación y edición de audio digital por medio de un software de edición de audio.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

To hover work you have to add ":hover" in front of the prop you want to hover with in css.
More on : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp
See how that works for you and if the relative position needs any change.